# Automatically Update Remote branch after push and tracking of files

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

1) How do I start tracking files in SourceTree?

2) I managed to commit+push successfully to a remote branch, but then the server requires you to ssh in and update. Can this be Automated with SourceTree?

Comment: Why do you need to update the working directory on your server?

Comment: Otherwise I won't see the changes?